# Math equation reference number added many times

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

When I run the following script

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Weights of the embedding layer}
\small
\begin{align}
\rlap{\text{Layer Weights}}\\
 &= \begin{bmatrix} -0.42056742 & -0.3540595 & -0.25417486 & -0.50596726 & -0.29918054\\ -0.23971583 & -0.39325562 & -0.35581827 & -0.3175518 & -0.2992685\\ -0.26149312 & -0.3268542 & -0.34264958 & -0.50005287 & -0.41450888\\ \ldots (m=60) 
\end{bmatrix}\\
& = \operatorname{shape}(5\times60)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I get many references per new line, like in the screenshot below

[image]

Apologize if the question is a dummy one. I am new in Latex and I do very common mistakes I guess.

Comment: `\notag` as in `\rlap{\text{Layer Weights}}\notag\\ ` could help here.

Comment: Align will number each row unless you tell it otherwise. If you just want one number, replace align by aligned and wrap equation around the whole thing. Aligned is an _inner_ version of align (meaning that is can only be used inside other math) but it adds no numbers

Comment: Both solutions worked

Answer (score 1):

The `align`, `gather`, `alignat` environments are for multiple equations, while the `multline` and `split` environments are for single equations.

The `split` environment provides no numbering because it is intended to be used only inside some other environment, such as `equation`.

You have just to replace your `align` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \rlap{\text{Layer Weights}}\\
    &= \begin{bmatrix} -0.42056742 & -0.3540595 & -0.25417486 & -0.50596726 & -0.29918054\\ -0.23971583 & -0.39325562 & -0.35581827 & -0.3175518 & -0.2992685\\ -0.26149312 & -0.3268542 & -0.34264958 & -0.50005287 & -0.41450888\\ \ldots (m=60) 
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    & = \operatorname{shape}(5\times60)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```